# JavaFX WebView getting a web address before returning a WebEngine

Tags: javafx, webview, popup

I am trying to create a pop handler for a web engine. Using the following code...

```
webView.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {
        public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures p) {
            //logic
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to know what web address is about to be sent to the returned web engine? My life becomes a lot easier if I can return a specifc web engine based on the web site being sent to it.

Any insight would be appreciated.